# Windows MDM AET token renewal for pushing Emails

Tags: azure, windows, mdm, company-hub

I have developed a Windows MDM applicatin along with it also pushes company emails on users devices. We need to also renew Application enrollment token every year.
I need to know if i  dont renew the AET than will it affect my mails or not

Answer (score 0):

The AET token is an `Application Enrollment Token`; it is needed solely to allow the enterprise app distribution for .xap/.appx/.appxbundle packages signed with a particular enterprise developer certificate.

Enrolling devices with AET is not required for calling SyncML CSPs (except those that deal with apps), and thus your e-mails won't be affected.